# Nodejs change function that gets filelist to also get content

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little function what gets the filenames with a specified extension in a given path.

Here is the code:

```
getFileList(path, extension) {
 let dir = fs.readdirSync( path );
 return dir.filter( elm => elm.match(new RegExp(`.*\.(${extension})`, 'ig')));
}
```

I am running this and adding the result to and array.

Like this:

```
myArray = getFileList('the path', 'ext');
```

This works fine I now need to add an object to the array with the filename and file content

For example:

```
myArray = []

getFileListAndContent('the path', 'ext'...);
```

resultExample:

```
myArray = [
  {
   filename: "filename1.ext",
   content: "the content"
  }
]
```

So I need it to return something like this (per file found):

```
 { filename: 'myfile1.doc', content: 'something here' }
```

How can I change the function so it does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all files and read their content one by one:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function getFileList(directory, extension) {
  let dir = fs.readdirSync(directory);
  let filelist = dir.filter( elm => elm.match(new RegExp(`.*\.(${extension})`, 'ig')));
  return filelist.map(file => {
    return {
      filename: file,
      content: fs.readFileSync(path.join(directory, file)).toString()
    }
  });
}

console.log(getFileList('path_here', 'doc'))
```

**NOTE** this is a synchronous solution.
If you have a long list of files, consider refactoring to the asynchronous format: `fs.readFile`

Comment: First of all synchronous  will be fine here as it's a very short list. I seem to have a problem when I try it like this: console.log(getFileList('path_here', 'doc')); It's returning this: ['myfile1.doc','myfile2.doc'] , no content ... I need something like: { filename: 'myfile1.doc', content: 'something here' }

Comment: Updated answer, please try again

Comment: Hmm...keeps throwing: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'myfile1.doc' .. I know the path is correct

Comment: Make sure you run the script from the same directory, or try with absolute path

Comment: The issue seems to be here... fs.readFileSync(file) ... could it be that it's expecting the full path to the file and it's just got the filename?

Comment: No. `fs.readFile` can also read relative paths. But now I notice that because `fs.readdir` returns only filenames, you must run the script from within the same directory where your files are, OR you should add the path to each file

Comment: Updated my answer, now you can run from everywhere